# I want to save response from api and re_used with next api ..without save to database?

Tags: php, api, rest, php-curl

```
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
            
//Output server response save here
 // print_r($curl_response);

This is the response:

{"MSISDN":"03142985338","OPT":304,"ResponceCode":"0020","ResponceMessage":"Success"}
```

I am trying to save "OTP" from the reponse beacuse i want it to use in another api

I am trying this method but it fail:

```
            $json_data = $curl_response;

            // Decode JSON data into PHP array
            $response_data = json_decode($json_data);
          
            
            // Print data if need to debug
            //print_r($user_data);
            
            
            echo "OTP: ".$curl_response->OTP;
```

Comment: If the API calls are not in the same script then you need to save the data somewhere...like a file or a database. What's the problem with a database?

Comment: api calls are in the same script

Comment: But are they both executed in the same iteration of that script? If so then you simply but the data in a variable. Its a bit unclear what the specific problem is. As the Answer below notes, is your real question about how to get certain items from within the data?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the data but I think you may have problem accessing it. I observe that a value with key **OPT** exists in the json you specified as response but you are accessing **OTP**? This may have resulted in you accessing a key that does not exist.
Other than that, I'd like to elaborate in case you need some guidance on accessing values for arrays:
To access the value of an element in a JSON object using the `json_decode` function in PHP, you can use the following syntax:

```
$json = '{"key": "value"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->key; // This will output value.
```

If you want to access an element in a JSON array, you can use the following syntax:

```
$json = '[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]';
$array = json_decode($json);
echo $array[0]->key; // This will output value1.
```

Note that `json_decode` takes a second parameter, `$assoc`, which when set to `true` will return the JSON data as an associative array instead of an object. In that case, you can access the elements using array syntax:

```
$json = '{"key": "value"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array['key']; // This will also output value.
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property 'OTP' of non-object

 $json_data = '{"OTP": }';
  $obj = json_decode($json_data);
  echo $obj->OTP; 
This error came when i try to get OTP value from response

Comment: @Villaro24 this is an error message that is typically encountered when you are trying to access a property (such as a field or method) of an object in your code, but the object is actually `null` or `undefined`. Are you sure the value corresponding to the **OTP** key is not empty? Try like this when trying to access it: `$obj->OTP ?? 'key value is null'`

Comment: sorry ITS OPT  i am trying to get only  OPT value from the response  beacuse i want it to use in any api